# Same code works locally but not from remote (Unexpected end of JSON input.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, raspberry-pi

I am developing a dual twin with a raspberry pi. I simulate having a continuous transmission of body temperature, and this is sent to a server that sends the data to a MongoDB database.
My code works perfectly locally, the communication has no problems.
However, when I move the temperature data generation to raspberry, simulating a real sensor, it gives me an error that says "Unexpected end of JSON input."

I will post both index.js and server.js, but I remind you that locally it is working perfectly.

```
const http = require('http')

//We are acting like there is a real sensor, so we need random float in range
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    let n = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    return Number(n).toFixed(1) //we stop at first decimal
}

//Read values to send every 2 sec
setInterval(function() {
    const date = new Date()
    const bodytemp = getRandomNumber(36.3, 36.8);
    console.log('Body temperature:', bodytemp + 'C');
    console.log(date.toString());

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        'sensor': 'Body Temperature',
        'timestamp': date.toString(),
        'temperature': bodytemp
    })

    const options = {

        hostname: '192.168.1.39',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/temperature',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    }

    const req = http.request(options, res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

        //define the callback function that will print the result of the request in case of success
        res.on('data', d => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        })

        //define the callback function that will print the result of the request in case of error
        req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    })
    //send the request
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}, 2000);
```

Obviously, the hostname's IP is being changed from localhost to my PC's IP.
And server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/TemperatureDB';

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    })
)

app.use(express.json());
app.post("/temperature", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body.temperature);
    var sensor = req.body.sensor;
    var temperature = req.body.temperature;
    var timestamp = req.body.timestamp;

    console.log(sensor);
    console.log(temperature);
    console.log(timestamp);

    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
    async function run() {

        try {

            await client.connect();

            const database = client.db("TemperatureDB");
            const temperatureColl = database.collection("temperature");
            // create a document to be inserted
            const doc = {
                sensor: sensor,
                value: temperature,
                timestamp: timestamp
                //roomId: 'room1' We could do set an ID for each driver
            };

            const result = await temperatureColl.insertOne(doc);
            console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documents were inserted with the _id: ${result.insertedId}`,);
        } finally {
            await client.close();
        }
    }

    run().catch(console.dir);
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

The error is that one

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /Users/samueleancora/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)
    at done (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

This is what the server is sending back

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/samueleancora/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/samueleancora/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:280:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working with a MacOS and with a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS (32 bit)

Comment: Check if, for any reason, your server is giving back to you an HTML error page or something similar, that is not JSON, and, instead, you are try to treat the unexpected HTML date as JSON. Maybe the JSON-related error message is hiding to you a different error to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing `.toString()` method to the `Date` object.